# Can't change property

Tags: javascript

I'm new to javascript and had some problems with updating properties. I've tried quite some different ways to solve this problem. Can someone tell me why I can't change the `_x` property of the `Acceleration` class.

```
var acceleration;

function Acceleration()
{
    this._x = 0;
    this.getX = function(){return this._x;};//This one always returns 0;
    this.onSuccess = function(e)
    {
        this._x = e.x;
        document.write( this._x + '<br/>');//This one changes.
        document.write( acceleration._x + '<br/>');//This one remains 0;
    }

    this.update = function()
    {
        intel.xdk.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(this.onSuccess, {adjustForRotation:false});
    }
}

function start()
{
    acceleration = new Acceleration();

    //Start the game.
    loop();
}

function loop()
{
    acceleration.update();
    setTimeout(loop, 1000);
}

document.addEventListener('intel.xdk.device.ready', start, false);
```

If I don't use `this` in front of `_x` it gives the same result.

Thank you!

Comment: The value of `this` won't be the object you want it to be when the framework calls your "onSuccess" method. Save `this` in another local variable and use that variable instead of  `this`.

Comment: again the mighty Scope slays a new innocent beginner :(

Comment: You might want to read some [`this` keyword docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), as `this` in JavaScript has some different behavior than other languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you @Pointy. I rewrote the function like this.

```
this.update = function()
{
    var object = this;
    intel.xdk.accelerometer.getCurrentAcceleration(
        function(e)
        {
            if(object._x == e.x && object._y == e.y && object._z == e.z){
                _changed = false;
            }else{
                object._x = e.x;
                object._y = e.y;
                object._z = e.z;
                _changed = true;
            }
        }, {adjustForRotation:false});
}
```

It seems work.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
var that = this;
this.getX = function(){return that._x;};
```

`this` in your function is not referring to your class object.
See this [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) about the keyword `this`.